# How to display all Database data in Grid View using Data Table?

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I have 5 data in my datatbase, these data I want to display in a gridView using Data Table. But my code displays only the last binded data in GridView? My code is. Please point out the mistake?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Date from MusterRoll where EmpCode='"+code+"' and Month='1' and Year='2015'", conn);
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet  ds = new DataSet();
 sda.Fill(ds);
 var rows = ds.Tables[0].Rows;
 foreach (DataRow row in rows)
  {
    string date1 = Convert.ToString(row["Date"]);
    DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date1);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" select TOP 1 m.EmpCode,m.NOH,m.OT,m.Late,m.Early,convert(varchar(10),m.Date,103)AS DATE,convert(varchar(10),s1.Shiftname,103)AS Shift From ShiftChange s,ShiftType s1,MusterRoll m  WHERE s1.ShiftID=s.NShiftID and '" + date2 + "'>=Fromdate and Todate>='" + date2 + "' and m.Month = '1' and m.date='"+date2+"' and m.EmpCode='Neena' order by Todate desc", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataTable  dt = new DataTable();
    sda1.Fill(dt);
    //var rows1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows;
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
      DataRow rpw = dt.Rows[rowIndex];
      string EmpCode = rpw.Field<string>("EmpCode");
      string NOH = rpw.Field<string>("NOH");
      string OT = rpw.Field<string>("OT");
      string Latae = rpw.Field<string>("Late");
      string Early = rpw.Field<string>("Early");
      string date3 =rpw.Field<string>("Date");
      string Shift = rpw.Field<string>("Shift");
      gvSingleemp.Visible = true;
      gvSingleemp.DataSource = dt;
      gvSingleemp.DataBind();
         }
        }
```

In my shiftChange table there is no Field for date instead of that I have fromDate and ToDate.I want display employee shifft according to MusterRoll table date. So that first I selected MusteRoll date nd checkrd this date exist in between ShiftChange FromDate and ToDate if exist show the Shift

Comment: By the way, don't use `dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()`  but `rpw.Field<string>("EmpCode")`. Your code always uses the first row instead of the current row in the loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You select dates, then you are looping them to select data from `EmpDetails` according to this date. But where do you want to show those records? Do you want multiple gridviews? If not, why don't you link `MusterRoll` and `EmpDetails` via `EmpCode`? Then you have all data in one query and the table contains all.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, ok can you guide me how to fill GridView using foreach loop  and DataTable

Comment: My point is that you don't need those loops. I guess that you want to select all records from  `EmpDetails`  where the `EmpCode` is `= code` and  the `MusterRoll.Month='1' and Year='2015'`. Then you only need one sql query to fill one `DataTable` which can be used as DataSource for `gvSingleemp`. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you write more code ? how do you use rpw after that ? when the for loop is closed ? sda is used or it's just sda1 ? ... Why do you want a for loop actually ?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, I have a database Musteroll which contains Some dates (2015-01-01,2015-02-02 etc..)
and I have another table EmpDetails which contains 5 data with different date but same month 1. 
first query generate a date and this date checks the data in EmpDetails with the same date.And again  generate next date using first query and select data from empdetails with that same date..like this. I think my english is a problem for you.

Comment: So you don't need loops for that

Comment: @SaraJohn: i have edited my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You are databinding the `GridView` in a loop. You don't need the loop, just bind it to the `DataTable`:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
DataTable  dt = new DataTable();
sda1.Fill(dt);
gvSingleemp.DataSource = dt;
gvSingleemp.DataBind();
```

I still think that   you don't need those loops at all. I guess that you want to select all records from  `EmpDetails`  where the `EmpCode = code` and  `MusterRoll.Month='1' and MusterRoll.Year='2015'`. Then you only need one sql query to fill one `DataTable` which can be used as DataSource for `gvSingleemp`. Is that correct?

If so, this should work (note that i use the `using` statement and sql-parameters):

```
DataTable tblData = new DataTable();
string sql = @"SELECT ed.EmpCode,ed.Name,ed.Age,ed.Date 
               FROM MusterRoll mr
               INNER JOIN EmpDetails ed 
                  ON mr.Date = ed.Date
               WHERE mr.EmpCode=@EmpCode AND mr.Month=1 AND mr.Year=2015";
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
using(var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
{
    var codeParam = new SqlParameter("@EmpCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = code; // change type accordingly
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(codeParam);
    sda.Fill(tblData); // no need for conn.Open/Close with SqlDataAdapter.Fill
}
gvSingleemp.Visible = true;
gvSingleemp.DataSource = tblData;
```

If you don't want to join the tables you can also use `EXISTS`:

```
string sql = @"SELECT ed.EmpCode, ed.Name, ed.Age, ed.Date 
               FROM  EmpDetails ed
               WHERE EXISTS
               (
                    SELECT 1 FROM MusterRoll mr
                    WHERE  mr.EmpCode = @EmpCode
                     AND   mr.Month = 1 AND mr.Year=2015
                     AND   mr.Date = ed.Date
               )";
```

Comment: Actually it is a big code that I made simple to answer you all I cant use without loop see my updated question

Comment: No I want to select records from EmpDetails where the Date= (dates which gets from first query). I mean if date=2014-01-01 then show only this date record from MusterRoll database

Comment: @SaraJohn: i have removed the join-condition that they need the same `EmpCode` but are only linked via Date. **Edit** Also provided an `EXISTS` approach which seems to be the best way.

Comment: Is there any other way to communicate to you.There I will show my whole code with database. What you are saying is absolutely  correct but it is not the thing which I want

Comment: @SaraJohn: then you have to explain it in detail _what_ you want :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use loop to bind the DT to GridView :

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(" select EmpCode,Name,Date,Age from  EmpDetails where CompanyID='1'", conn);
 SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
 DataTable  dt = new DataTable();
 sda1.Fill(dt);
 gvSingleemp.DataSource =dt;
 gvSingleemp.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable  data = new DataTable();

Da.Fill(data);

gvSingleemp.DataSource = data;

gvSingleemp.DataBind();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on how this could solve the question?